# How to float my div at the very bottom of my content

Tags: css, position, footer

How can I float my div at the very bottom of my content?
So at the end of my page no mater how long it is (generated by content) I want to have some kind of footer, but i don't want to use the footer tag please, I need to implement it in other pages aswel.

In this case it is about the division class="bottom"

My code is below

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=yes">
    <title>Moworkflow app</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="advertentie.css" />
<head>
<body>

<!-- wrapper -->
<div id="wrapper">  

<!-- header -->
<div id="header" align="center">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">img logo</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Aanbod</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Vraag</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<!-- filter -->
<div id="filter">
</div>


<!-- content -->
<div id="content" align="center">
    <table cellspacing="10" class="tablestyle">
      <tr>
        <td><h3>Advertentiegegevens</h3></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Soortnaam</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" class="invoerveld"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Kleur</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" class="invoerveld"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Aantal</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" class="invoerveld"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Prijs</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" class="invoerveld"></td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<!-- bottom --> 
<div id="bottom" align="center">
</div>
</body>
</html>

body {
    margin:0; 
    width:100vw;
    background:#fff;
    font-family: arial; 
}

#wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 456px;
    width: 100%;
}

#header {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background: #0d82d7;
    z-index: 4;
    opacity: 0.96;
}

ul {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    list-style: none;
    padding-left:0;
    margin:0;
}

li {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 60px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #0d82d7;
}

li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}



#filter {
    background: #0873c0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    z-index: 3;
    opacity: 0.96;


}






 #content {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
    top: 70px;
   margin-top: 20px;
    bottom: 30px;
    display: table;
    z-index: 0;
}

.tablestyle {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
}

.invoerveld {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-color: #0d82d7;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;

}


#bottom {
    position: relative;   
    width: 100%;  
    background-color: #0d82d7;  
    height: 30px;
    bottom: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    opacity: 0.9;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change bottom ID css with this:

```
#bottom {
    position: fixed;   
    width: 100%;  
    background-color: #0d82d7;  
    height: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    opacity: 0.9;
    bottom:0;
}
```

Also check jsfiddle, you want it to be like this or not?

http://jsfiddle.net/ew6xyp66/

Comment: This is just fixed, I don't want it to be visual all time it needs to float below the content.

Comment: OP asks for footer to float below content no matter how long, in your solution the footer is stuck to the bottom of page regardless of content height ... if it's longer > http://jsfiddle.net/ew6xyp66/1/

Answer (score 0):

If you want your footer to follow your content, you should remove this:

```
#content    {position:absolute;}
```

The reason is, absolute positioned elements are taken out of the pages normal flow therefore the following sibling elements are not positioned under them as they normally would.

UPDATE:
to avoid footer+content being shorter than browser height you could give your content 100% height minus the height of your header.. something like this:

```
#content {min-height:calc(100% - 50px);}
```

Browser support: http://caniuse.com/#search=calc

[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/x628q2jt/1/)

Comment: Looks nice, thank you. It floats nice below the content but now if the content is smaller then the browser size, the footer will end up in the middle of the screen. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Yes, you could use calc to give a min height.. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Yes this is awesome but I see my content moved up now. the content isn't in the state it was before. Has this anything to do with your changes? It moved up below my navigation/headerbar

Comment: Sure, what's happening is your header+filler elements are fixed so you need give your content matching padding so it starts right after them.. so header+filler heights = 90px.. give content padding-top 90px.. also I changed the min-height to reduce the footer height as it should.. check the code > http://jsfiddle.net/x628q2jt/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
.bottom {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;right:0;
    margin:auto auto;
}
```

this aligns an element to the bottom of something, if you want it contained then give the parent `position:relative;`